# What is a pseudocode implementation of this context-free language enumerator?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, language-agnostic, grammar, context-free-grammar

[This blog post](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/enumerating-a-context-free-language/) in Haskell explains how context-free grammars can be enumerated with aid of a monad called Omega.

I could not understand how this works partly due to the lack of an explanation on how that monad works, but mostly due to the fact I can't understand monads. What is a proper pseudo-code explanation of that algorithm, **without monads**?

Using a syntax similar to a simple, common language such as JavaScript or Python would be preferred.

Comment: I tagged this with Haskell given you need to understand the original blogpost in Haskell to answer, even if you do stick to the request to use a less functional language in the answer.

Comment: With that answer you can do everything you want with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Haskell version without the monad. I do use list comprehensions but those
are more intuitive and you have them in Python as well.

The `Omega` type is just a wrapper around `[]`, but it helps to keep the "string of symbols" and the "list of possible strings" concepts separate. Since we're not going to use `Omega` for "list of possible strings", let's use a `newtype` wrapper for "string of symbols" to keep everything straight:

```
import Prelude hiding (String)

-- represent a sequence of symbols of type `a`,
-- i.e. a string recognised by a grammar over `a`
newtype String a = String [a]
    deriving Show

-- simple wrapper for (++) to also make things more explicit when we use it
joinStrings (String a1) (String a2) = String (a1 ++ a2)
```

Here's the `Symbol` type from the blogpost:

```
data Symbol a
    = Terminal a
    | Nonterminal [[Symbol a]] -- a disjunction of juxtapositions
```

The core of the `Omega` monad is actually the [`diagonal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html#v%3adiagonal) function:

```
-- | This is the hinge algorithm of the Omega monad,
-- exposed because it can be useful on its own.  Joins 
-- a list of lists with the property that for every x y 
-- there is an n such that @xs !! x !! y == diagonal xs !! n@.
diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

Given this, `enumerate` from the blogpost was:

```
enumerate :: Symbol a -> Omega [a]
enumerate (Terminal a) = return [a]
enumerate (Nonterminal alts) = do
    alt <- each alts          -- for each alternative
      -- (each is the Omega constructor :: [a] -> Omega a)
    rep <- mapM enumerate alt -- enumerate each symbol in the sequence
    return $ concat rep       -- and concatenate the results
```

Our `enumerate` will have this type:

```
enumerate :: Symbol a -> [String a]
```

The `Terminal` case is easy:

```
enumerate (Terminal a) = [String [a]]
```

In the `Nonterminal` case a helper function for each alternative will
be useful:

```
-- Enumerate the strings accepted by a sequence of symbols
enumerateSymbols :: [Symbol a] -> [String a]
```

The base case is quite easy, though the result isn't `[]`, but
a singleton result containing the empty string:

```
enumerateSymbols [] = [String []]
```

For the non-empty case another helper will be useful to pair up
the strings from the head and from the tail in all possible ways,
using `diagonal`:

```
crossProduct :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
crossProduct as bs = diagonal [[(a, b) | b <- bs] | a <- as]
```

I could also have written `[[(a, b) | a <- as] | b <- bs]` but
I chose the other because that ends up replicating the output from
the blogpost.

Now we can write the non-empty case for `enumerateSymbols`:

```
enumerateSymbols (sym:syms) =
    let prefixes = enumerate sym
        suffixes = enumerateSymbols syms
    in [joinStrings prefix suffix 
           | (prefix, suffix) <- crossProduct prefixes suffixes]
```

and now the non-empty case for `enumerate`:

```
enumerate (Nonterminal alts) =
    -- get the list of strings for each of the alternatives
    let choices = map enumerateSymbols alts
    -- and use diagonal to combine them in a "fair" way
    in diagonal choices
```

Here's the body of `diagonal` from the Omega source, with my
explanations:

```
diagonal = diagonal' 0
    where

    -- strip n xss returns two lists,
    -- the first containing the head of each of the first n lists in xss,
    -- the second containing the tail of the first n lists in xss
    -- and all of the remaining lists in xss.
    -- empty lists in xss are ignored
    stripe 0 xss          = ([],xss)
    stripe n []           = ([],[])
    stripe n ([]:xss)     = stripe n xss
    stripe n ((x:xs):xss) = 
        let (nstripe, nlists) = stripe (n-1) xss
        in (x:nstripe, xs:nlists)


    -- diagonal' n xss uses stripe n to split up
    -- xss into a chunk of n elements representing the
    -- nth diagonal of the original input, and the rest
    -- of the original input for a recursive call to
    -- diagonal' (n+1)

    diagonal' _ [] = []
    diagonal' n xss =
        let (str, xss') = stripe n xss
        in str ++ diagonal' (n+1) xss'
```

It's also worth reading [this paper](http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/~mike/bfs/bfs.ps) about the general concept of diagonalization and breadth-first search of an infinite structure.